# How to work with images from api in nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have started working with Nuxt and I have a general question about image handling, it may be something very obvious that I am missing.
I use the Wordpress rest api as my data source and I want to create a static site with nuxt generate.
My question is how can I copy the images from Wordpress to the generated static site? All I can find on the documentation asumes that images are already in the assets folder. In my case the images are in a wordpress installation on a different somain and server and I can access their data and url from the rest api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like that plugin: https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/ which would copy your images to a space like Amazon S3 or Digital Ocean Space.

It would change the url in Wordpress automatically and therefore you get the right image location in your API calls. You can then even connect your space to a CDN which makes the image delivery even faster.

I'm using that in several projects with success.

Comment: It is different from what I was thinking but it looks like a great solution